# Separating transaction log files from database files in two different physical drives

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, windows-server-2012-r2

I am very new to this as it is my first time installing the product,

I have installed SQL Server 2014 enterprise edition on Windows Server 2012 R2 standard edition using the default installation, which means everything in one physical drive (C drive).

Now SQL server is installed and running, but I did not move my database there yet.

My question is, how can I change the settings to make both transaction logs and the database in two different physical drives?

I have C drive for the OS (Windows Server 2012 R2)
So far everything on C drive, but I want to put the transaction logs on D drive and the databases on E drive.

In a simple word, can I change into the below structure before moving my data?

- C: OS and SQL installation files
- D: SQL Server Transaction Log Files
- E: SQL Server Database
  Files

Comment: I am not sure yet, but I found that when I open SQL Server Management Studio, right click on the server, select properties, click on Database Settings, and then I can specify the path of the Data, Log, Backup. I hope this is the right place?

Comment: You can find the necessary info here:
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52007/how-do-i-move-sql-server-database-files

Comment: Thank you very much! This is definitely helpful

Comment: In my case, I can use the option from the server properties where I can set the default location since I did not move my data to the new server. If I already have data, then I would need to follow the procedure. Thank you very much though!

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to follow the below process it may helps you   

 --> Right click on the name of the database
    --> Select Properties
    --> Go to the Files tab
    --> Make a note of the Path and FileName of MDF and LDF files. This step is important in case you don't want to end up searching for missing files...
    --> Right click on the database name
    --> Select Tasks -> Detach
    --> Move the files where you want
    --> Right click on the Databases node of your server
    --> Select Attach
    --> Click on the Add button
    --> Point to the new location
    --> Click OK
```